# Yii2 console app error 'Failed to instantiate component or class "user".'

Tags: yii2

I'm pretty new to Yii2. I created a frontend Yii2 app and now I want to define a cronjob that would call some action every night.

I created a simple console app for that, following the tutorial from here: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2, with the following code:

```
namespace console\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;

class CronController extends Controller {
    public function actionIndex() {
        echo "cron service runnning";
    }
}
```

I try to call it by running this:

```
php yii cron/index
```

But I get the following error:

```
    Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Failed to instantiate component or class "user".'

in /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php:139

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php(100): yii\di\Instance::ensure(Object(yii\di\Instance), 'yii\\web\\User')
#1 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(107): yii\filters\AccessControl->init()
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(381): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\filters\\Acc...', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(348): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\filters\\Acc...', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(183): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(529): yii\base\Component->__set('beforeRequest', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Application), Array)
#9 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(205): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#10 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(89): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#11 /var/www/html/my-yii2-app/yii(26): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#12 {main}
```

Content of common/config/main.php:

```
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
    ],

    //if guest user access site so, redirect to login page.
    'as beforeRequest' => [  
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    // end if guest user access site so, redirect to login page.
    'language' => 'ro-RO',

    'modules' => [
        'attachments' => [
            'class' => nemmo\attachments\Module::className(),
            'tempPath' => '@app/../uploads/temp',
            'storePath' => '@app/../uploads/store',
            'rules' => [ // Rules according to the FileValidator
                'maxFiles' => 10, // Allow to upload maximum 3 files, default to 3
                //'mimeTypes' => 'image/png', // Only png images
                //'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 // 1 MB
            ],
            //'tableName' => '{{%attachments}}' // Optional, default to 'attach_file'
            'tableName' => 'attachment' // Optional, default to 'attach_file'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Content of console/config/main.php:

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'controllerMap' => [
        'fixture' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\FixtureController',
            'namespace' => 'common\fixtures',
          ],
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
            'migrationNamespaces' => [
                'nemmo\attachments\migrations',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

I have no idea what could be wrong.

OS: CentOS 7, PHP version 7

Comment: Can you show full stack trace? Is this is complete code of your `CronController`?

Comment: @rob006 I just added the full stack trace. And yes, the code of CronController is exactly the one I posted. Nothing more.

Comment: Show config of your application. Do you accessing `Yii::$app->user` inside of `beforeRequest` callback?

Comment: @rob006, I just added two config files. Are they enough? Do you want me to add any additional ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> //if guest user access site so, redirect to login page.
> 'as beforeRequest' => [  
>     'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
>     'rules' => [
>         [
>             'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
>             'allow' => true,
>         ],
>         [
>             'allow' => true,
>             'roles' => ['@'],
>         ],
>     ],
> ],
> ```

This part of config is a problem. `AccessControl` does not have any sense in console application config (there is no `Yii:$app->user` for console application). Since you're setting it in common config, it is also used in configuration of console application.

You should move this setting at higher level, probably to `frontend/config/main.php` and `backend/config/main.php`, so it will be used only for web applications.

Comment: Great! Moved that part to frontend/config/main.php and now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!